# multiple choice question on ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Pick out the true statement(s):
(a) The set of all $2×2$ matrices with rational entries (with the usual operations of matrix addition and matrix multiplication) is a ring which has no non-trivial ideals.
(b) Let $R = C [0, 1$] be considered as a ring with the usual operations of pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Let
I = {$f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R} | f (1/2) = 0$}.
Then $I$ is a maximal ideal.
(c) Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$  be a prime ideal of $R$. Then $R/P$ is an integral domain.

I know that (c) is true but not sure about the others.

Comment: all three are true    for a> look at ideals of $\mathbb Q$ and what is its relation with ideals of the matrix ring with rational entries.

Answer (score 1):

(a) What are the left ideals of this ring? The right ideals? Hint: Use the left action of this ring on $\mathbb{Q}^2$ to describe the left ideals, and the right action of the ring (via the transpose) to describe the right ideals.

(b) Show that I is an ideal. Then it is a kernel of some homomorphism. What is its image?

Comment: b is ok.thanks.

Comment: but would you explain (a) please.

Comment: This is the ring of linear maps $\mathbb{Q}^2\to \mathbb{Q}^2$. The  nontrivial left ideals are the annihilators of lines.

Answer (score 0):

option a. is true, because for any field F, Mn(F) does not have any non trivial ideal.option b. is true, because in C[0,1], M(a)={f in c[0,1] such that f(a)=0}, these ideals are exactly the form of any maximal ideal for a in [0,1]. I think option c. is false if unity in the definition of integral domain is necessary and true if not necessary. According to me the there is no need of an unity in an integral domain because any ring can be embedded to a ring with unity.